# Squaring the Gamma Function

Tags: functions, notation

Gamma of n is the function which I want to square. This is for use in a formula. Should the n be in parentheses and then the function in brackets or should the gamma and n be in parentheses? It should read (gamma of n) squared. This is the upper case gamma for n-1 factorial, where n is a positive integer.

Comment: $\Gamma^2(n)$ or $(\Gamma(n))^2$. $\Gamma(n)^2$ is also acceptable, but certainly not $\Gamma n^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Agree, although I would more often than not use $\Gamma^2(n)$, in the same way as $\cos^2(x)$ or $\log^2(x)$, aesthetically speaking.

Comment: Personally, I think $\Gamma^2 (n)$ looks a bit too much like functional power (i.e. like it means $\Gamma (\Gamma (n))$).

Comment: I would use $\Gamma^2(n)$, it looks way cooler. It's pretty standard also.